# How can I iterate over Java Bean properties in Play 2 Scala template?

Tags: scala, reflection, playframework, javabeans

Suppose I have a Java bean:

```
class Fruit {
    public String getName(){}
    public String getOrigin(){}
    public int getRipeningTimeInDays(){}
}
```

And there's a Play 2.0 scala template which takes a fruit parameter

```
@(obj: Object)
@** add code for rendering JavaBeans properties via reflection
```

I would like to be able to render all the Java Bean's properties via reflection. Is there a simple way of doing it in scala or should I resort Apache commons beanutils etc.?

Comment: Whats wrong with a typed template parameter @(fruit: Fruit)? After all, thats the point of having typed templates, not?

Comment: I was trying to write a generic view for developers, that would let them dump any object